# Encoding HttpURLConnection Parameter work in marshmallow but not in jellybean

Tags: android, encoding, version

```
 public static String getJson(String url, int timeout) {
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    try {
        url = url.replace("%20", " ");
        URL u = new URL(url);
        URI uri = new URI(u.getProtocol(), u.getUserInfo(), u.getHost(), 
u.getPort(), u.getPath(), u.getQuery(), u.getRef());
        u = uri.toURL();
        c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        c.setDoOutput(true);
        c.setDoInput(true);
        c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        c.setRequestMethod("POST");
        c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        c.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
        c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");

        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                br.close();
                return sb.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "Error Connection";
    } 
    return "Error Connection";
}
```

when test on marshmallow parameters with spaces or in arabic language encoding and decoding 
but when test on jellybean encoding not work 
please help me to fix this probelm